# Power Query and VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new at this but work with a bigger project to learn `VBA`, but now I am stuck. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

In `sheet1` I run a macro that calls another macro in `sheet2`, which again runs a module. When I create a table in `sheet2`, to use Power query in my workbook, the macros do not work anymore. I get the following message:

> "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error."

By removing bits and pieces of the macros, I found that the problem seems to be the module. In this module I have written as follows (I am open for a shorter way of writing this, but I'm new at this):

```
Sub fagrekke_dato2()


If Ark1.[E8].Value = 1 Then
Call DateFiller_endd1
Call DateFiller_startt1
Call DateFiller_endt1
End If

If Ark1.[E8].Value = 2 Then
Call DateFiller_endd1
Call DateFiller_startt1
Call DateFiller_endt1
Call DateFiller_endd2
Call DateFiller_startt2
Call DateFiller_endt2
End If

If Ark1.[E8].Value = 3 Then
Call DateFiller_endd1
Call DateFiller_startt1
Call DateFiller_endt1
Call DateFiller_endd2
Call DateFiller_startt2
Call DateFiller_endt2
Call DateFiller_endd3
Call DateFiller_startt3
Call DateFiller_endt3
End If

Range("E2:E200").Copy Destination:=Range("B2") 'forbedre?



End Sub

Sub DateFiller_endd1()

Dim k, l As Date
l = Cells(2, 5).Value
For k = 2 To Rows.Count Step Ark1.[E8].Value
Cells(k, 5).Value = l
l = l + 7
If Cells(k, 5).Value + 6 > Ark1.Cells(3, 4).Value Then Exit Sub
Next k
End Sub

Sub DateFiller_endt1()

Dim o, p As Date
p = Cells(2, 6).Value
For o = 2 To Rows.Count Step Ark1.[E8].Value
Cells(o, 6).Value = p
If Cells(o, 5).Value + 6 > Ark1.Cells(3, 4).Value Then Exit Sub
Next o
End Sub

Sub DateFiller_startt1()

Dim i, j As Date
j = Cells(2, 4).Value
For i = 2 To Rows.Count Step Ark1.[E8].Value
Cells(i, 4).Value = j
If Cells(i, 5).Value + 6 > Ark1.Cells(3, 4).Value Then Exit Sub
Next i
End Sub


Sub DateFiller_startt2()

Dim i, j As Date
j = Cells(3, 4).Value
For i = 3 To Rows.Count Step Ark1.[E8].Value
Cells(i, 4).Value = j
If Cells(i, 5).Value + 6 > Ark1.Cells(3, 4).Value Then Exit Sub
Next i
End Sub


Sub DateFiller_endd2()

Dim k, l As Date
l = Cells(3, 5).Value
For k = 3 To Rows.Count Step Ark1.[E8].Value
Cells(k, 5).Value = l
l = l + 7
If Cells(k, 5).Value + 6 > Ark1.Cells(3, 4).Value Then Exit Sub
Next k
End Sub

Sub DateFiller_endt2()

Dim o, p As Date
p = Cells(3, 6).Value
For o = 3 To Rows.Count Step Ark1.[E8].Value
Cells(o, 6).Value = p
If Cells(o, 5).Value + 6 > Ark1.Cells(3, 4).Value Then Exit Sub
Next o
End Sub
Sub DateFiller_startt3()

Dim i, j As Date
j = Cells(4, 4).Value
For i = 4 To Rows.Count Step Ark1.[E8].Value
Cells(i, 4).Value = j
If Cells(i, 5).Value + 6 > Ark1.Cells(3, 4).Value Then Exit Sub
Next i
End Sub


Sub DateFiller_endd3()

Dim k, l As Date
l = Cells(4, 5).Value
For k = 4 To Rows.Count Step Ark1.[E8].Value
Cells(k, 5).Value = l
l = l + 7
If Cells(k, 5).Value + 6 > Ark1.Cells(3, 4).Value Then Exit Sub
Next k
End Sub

Sub DateFiller_endt3()

Dim o, p As Date
p = Cells(4, 6).Value
For o = 4 To Rows.Count Step Ark1.[E8].Value
Cells(o, 6).Value = p
If Cells(o, 5).Value + 6 > Ark1.Cells(3, 4).Value Then Exit Sub
Next o
End Sub
```

The point of this module is to estimate the date and time for events that happen from one to three times a week. I do believe the problem is that the table does not manage to define its length.

I may add that i use this module in a loop, where I check if there are any holidays or activities that conflict with the plan. If so the plan for all dates are updated:

```
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, lr As Long, fn As Range, sr As Range, rng As Range, n As Long
Set sh1 = Me 
Set sh2 = Ark13 
lr = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lr Step 1

Set fn = sh2.Range("E:E").Find(sh1.Cells(i, 5).Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
If Not fn Is Nothing Then
Set sr = fn.Offset(0, 1)                    
Set er = sr.End(xlDown)
Set rng = sr
n = rng.Rows.Count
rng.EntireRow.Copy
sh1.Cells(i, 1).Resize(n).EntireRow.Insert
Call fagrekke_dato2
End If
Ark1.Range("D27:F29").Copy
Cells(2, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next
```

Do anybody know why creating a table in sheet2 end up beeing a problem?

Comment: Do you know what line the error is occurring on?

Comment: No, but i seem to be an issue with estimating the length of the table:

Comment: I run this script as part of a loop in sheet2, which also might be the problem. The loop is as follows:

Comment: Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, lr As Long, fn As Range, sr As Range, rng As Range, n As Long
Set sh1 = Me 'Edit sheet name
Set sh2 = Ark13 'Edit sheet name
lr = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: For i = 2 To lr Step 1
        
        Set fn = sh2.Range("E:E").Find(sh1.Cells(i, 5).Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
            If Not fn Is Nothing Then
                Set sr = fn.Offset(0, 1)
                    Set er = sr.End(xlDown)
                    Set rng = sr
                n = rng.Rows.Count
                rng.EntireRow.Copy
                sh1.Cells(i, 1).Resize(n).EntireRow.Insert
           Call fagrekke_dato2
            End If
   Ark1.Range("D33:F35").Copy
Cells(2, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next